# python embedding, defining new type, How can I create a new instance in c side

Tags: python, cpython

I'm reading [python c Defining New Types](https://docs.python.org/zh-cn/2.7/extending/newtypes.html). I can't figure out, After I defined the new type, how can I create a new instance of Noddy in c side. For example create a method `noddy.create_default_noddy`.

I have tried this. but no lucky.

```cpp
static PyObject *noddy_createDefaultNoddy(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    // yes we can't create an object like this.
    auto *noddy = new Noddy;
    return (PyObject *)noddy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some reading code. I figure out the right way is:

```
static PyObject *noddy_getDefaultNoddy(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    Noddy *foo;

    foo = (Noddy*)noddyType.tp_alloc(&noddyType, 0);
    foo->first = Py_BuildValue("%s", "first name from c");
    assert(foo != nullptr);
    return (PyObject*)foo;
}
```